# Using Jackson As.External_Property with a Collection

Tags: java, json, jackson

Trying to serialize (and then deserialize) a container with a list of subtypes using [JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonTypeInfo.As.html#EXTERNAL_PROPERTY). 
I get

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerationException: Can not write a field name, expecting a value
```

when Jackson tries to write the collection (`elements`)

```
public class Container {

public static final TypeReference<Container> CONTAINER_REF = new TypeReference<Container>() {
    // nothing extra
};

@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.NAME, include = As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY)
@JsonSubTypes({
      @Type(value = ChildOne.class, name = "childOne"),
      @Type(value = ChildTwo.class, name = "childTwo"),
      })
private List<? extends Parent<?>> elements;

public Container() {
   super();
}

public List<? extends Parent<?>> getElements() {
    return elements;
}

public void setElements(List<? extends Parent<?>> elements) {
    this.elements = elements;
}
```

}

```
@JsonSubTypes({
@Type(value = ChildOne.class, name = "childOne"),
@Type(value = ChildTwo.class, name = "childTwo"),
})
public abstract class Parent<T> {

public Parent() {
    super();
}

public abstract T getSomething();

public static class ChildOne extends Parent<String> {
    public ChildOne() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public String getSomething() {
        return "lala";
    }
}

public static class ChildTwo extends Parent<Long> {
    public ChildTwo() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public Long getSomething() {
        return 764L;
    }
}
```

}

Note that I want the `type` property to be *part of the container* and **not** per each item in the collection.

**EDIT:**

I've ended up using [JsonTypeInfo.As.Property](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonTypeInfo.As.html#PROPERTY) instead, with two subclasses of `Container` and a `type` property that each subclass has to implement returning it's class name

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible to do. Your `Collection` declaration can either indicate uniform non-polymorphic type, or base of polymorphic type. But it can not force contents.